# Arrows not working on input type="number"

Tags: html, css

I used a simple html

```
<input type="number">
```

It is showing a text box with up and down arrows but the arrows are not working. The value can be incremented/decremented with arrows on keyboard and mouse scroll, but when I click on any of the arrows, it seems that the down arrow is clicked and the value in the box remains the same. Please suggest what should I do!

Comment: on every browser. and for now I am using Google Chrome

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle or share a link? It's hard to know if some Javascript is conflicting with the input (which is my initial guess) or if an element is overlaid on top of the input.

Comment: Share your code. It's working on every browser on my pc.

Comment: @MillerMedia I have checked it, but nothing is overlaid :(. And Sorry not able to share the fiddle. As it's only a specific case, otherwise it is working. Let me check id I can make the proper fiddle, with the input type not working.

Comment: @SuryaPurohit please send jsfiddle file

Comment: @SuryaPurohit, my best guess would be that there is some Javascript on the page. If this is a link that you can't share, I would first try to disable all your Javascript files that are loading and try it (even if other elements on the page are messed up). If the input then works, you can isolate from there. If you get a fiddle working or a link to look at I'd be happy to help there as well.

Comment: Disable javascript from the browser console and see what happens.

Comment: @MillerMedia frenchie Fed Up :(. Not able to produce the case on fiddle. I've disabled each Javascript from the console but nothing happened. I kept the html of the input type only. I was not working on that particular tab. Working on another tabs.

Comment: It'll surely be a JS which is conflicting but not able to recognise that

Comment: Have you removed the JS files that are being loaded?

Comment: Also check inheriting properties and make sure there are not JavaScript events attached.

Comment: Oh Gosh... a class can make this effect huh. I was using ember and the div in which I was using input type="number" was having class "ember-view". After so much of attempts removing JS CSS n all. Come to know that ember-view class was creating the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue and am not using ember, just jQuery on the page :(

Comment: Oh, I have made a fiddle to reproduce this consistently in Chrome. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much of attempts removing JS CSS n all. Come to know that "ember-view" class was creating the issue. I was using ember and the div in which I was using input type="number" was having class "ember-view". Removing that class makes the textbox work good :). Thanks.
Earlier

```
<div class="ember-view">
<input type="number">
</div>
```

Now

```
<div>
<input type="number">
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Well I'm surprised by this but it looks like a bug, at least in Chrome. (Edge doesn't show the arrows at all and Firefox behaves correctly.)

The mousemove event listener (on the element or the document) breaks the INPUT TYPE="number" if an e.preventDefault() is present:

```
<input type="number" value="1"/>

$(function() {
    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/MCAU/Lpojfrm2/

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Oh! Interesting that if you change 'mousemove' to 'mouseup', Chrome increments / decrements the numbers quickly. See https://jsfiddle.net/MCAU/2w3do8d9/1/

Comment: confirmed, chrome input number seem to rely in onmousemove returning true

Comment: Good detective work. I can confirm this is still the case in 2019.

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this:**

**HTML**

```
<div id="incdec">
<input type="text" value="0" />
<img src="up_arrow.jpeg" id="up" />
<img src="down_arrow.jpeg" id="down" />
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#up").on('click',function(){
    $("#incdec input").val(parseInt($("#incdec input").val())+1);
});

$("#down").on('click',function(){
    $("#incdec input").val(parseInt($("#incdec input").val())-1);
});

});
```

Comment: Sorry but can't try this. I need to use those arrows

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<input type="number" step="1" >
```

Here in step option give the value you want to increment or decrement to the value.i.e if you set step=0.5 and your value is 5 on click up arrow it will change the value to 5.5

I hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try it.
input field need focus to increment/decrement value.

```
<input type="number" autofocus="autofocus">
```

Comment: thanks but we can gain focus when click on the textbox, furthermore the arrows are always clickable :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me arrows were displayed on desktop Chrome but I tried so hard to restore arrows form mobile browsers like mobile Chrome, I tried many solutions without success.

Eventually I decided to make some nice buttons on the sides of the input. I made the code and you can add as many buttons as you want as long as you respect the id numeration. I invite you to look at the snippet I posted on this other similar post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68679616/13795525